# How to access appsettings from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the startup file I need a way to access IConfiguration in another project. I have been told the Business Logic should not know about IConfiguration. If thats the case then how do I inject data from appsettings down to the business logic projects.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AdminEmail": "myemail@gmail.com"
}
```

How would I access AdminEmail in a class library I created in the same solution?

Comment: Appsettings is just a file, not something special like app.config or web.config were. If something wants to use the configuration services of .NET Core it *has* to use `IConfiguration` to specify which sections should be rehydrated into which objects. If you want to use DI to populate config settings, you need to wrap them into IOption<>. On the other hand if you simply inject the settings as plain old objects, only the main project needs to deal with IConfiguration

Comment: @RyanWilson that's actually an *abuse*. The *controller* shouldn't care about IConfiguration, it should care about its own settings classes *only*, eg `EmailSettings`. Why should you mock or spin up the entire middleware if you only want to pass an `EmailSettings` class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Define a model for settings

  ```
  public sealed class EmailSettings
  {
      public string AdminEmail { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Configure settings

  ```
  public sealed class Startup
  {
      private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => this.configuration = configuration;

      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services
              .Configure<EmailSettings>(configuration)
              .AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EmailSettings>>().Value);
      }
  }
  ```
- Inject and use it

  ```
  public class ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution
  {
      public ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution(EmailSettings emailSettings)
      {                         
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: In which project is the EmailSettings defined? The "top" project which contains the appsettings.json or the class library?

If it is defined in "top" project, then you cannot inject it like you did, because the class library does not know of the type EmailSettings.

Comment: @MarioMucalo the class library should know of the type ```EmailSettings``` because the type is used in the constructor ```public ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution(EmailSettings emailSettings)```. Just define the class ```EmailSettings``` in the class library project or in the other separate project (e.g Infrastructure.Settings).

Comment: I agree... However, is this true decoupling then? :)

Comment: it may be too late to ask a question on this but I think I have a similar scenario as above. 

Assuming your ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution class is in some another project and your services.Configure code is in some another project. Keeping in mind EmailSettings is know by both the projects

How do call your method defined in the class ? 

If using ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution obj= new ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution (); is the one then do you get the configuration values in construction. As I am facing compile time error on this for all the obvious reasons.

Comment: @AdityaPewekar Defining a constructor with a parameter ```ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution(EmailSettings emailSettings) { }``` hides a default constructor without parameter. That's why you have an error trying to use it.

Comment: Yes, then in this case how can i get the configuration form my constructor and use the same in the method defined in the class. I am facing issue when having a parameterized constructor as to access the class method i need to create their object's.

Comment: @AdityaPewekar the above configuration example shows how to use DI (dependency injection). In this case you don't need to create manually an instance of the class ```ClassLibraryInTheSameSolution```. And a dependent instance of the ```EmailSettings``` class will be injected by DI-container.

Comment: Hey Andriy, i got the answer to my question as i was giving a wrong thought on DI. Thanks for replying and giving a breakthrough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to achieve this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration

**1 - Create a model for the settings**

```
public class AppSettings 
{
    public string AdminEmail { get; set; }
}
```

**2 - Configure it on Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
```

**3 - Use DI in your class library to retrieve the settings**

```
private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

public MyClass(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could inject it quite easily:

```
public class EmailSettings
{
    public string AdminEmail { get; set; } // encapsulate as needed
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var settings = new EmailSettings
    {
        AdminEmail = Configuration["AdminEmail"]
    };

    services.AddSingleton(settings);
}

public class WhereverYouNeedThis
{
    private readonly EmailSettings _emailSettings;

    public WhereverYouNeedThis(EmailSettings emailSettings)
    {
        _emailSettings = emailSettings;
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        Debug.Log(_emailSettings.AdminEmail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This helper class provider:**

```
public class AppSettings
{
    private static AppSettings _appSettings;

    public string appSettingValue { get; set; }

    public static string Get(string Key)
    {
        _appSettings = GetCurrentSettings(Key);
        return _appSettings.appSettingValue;
    }

    public AppSettings(IConfiguration config, string Key)
    {
        this.appSettingValue = config.GetValue<string>(Key);
    }

    public static AppSettings GetCurrentSettings(string Key)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

        var settings = new AppSettings(configuration, Key);

        return settings;
    }
}
```

**To use that helper, you should install all this packages:**

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

**Examples how you could use that in your code:**

```
AppSettings.Get("SomeKey");
AppSettings.Get("Redis:Host");
AppSettings.Get("ConnectionString:mssql");
```