# Accessing appsettings.json values in different project in WPF .NET Core app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am new to .NET core and currently playing around with a WPF .NET Core app. I structured my solution with three different projects: `View`, `ViewModel` and `Model`.

My `Model` contains the business logic and in it I fetch invoice data from different sources. Now I need to exclude invoices with certain invoice numbers. I decided to define these numbers inside the appsettings.json file. After some research I learned I must initialize the IConfigurationBuilder instance inside the `OnStartup()` method in the `App.xaml.cs` file in the `View` project. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562798/reading-appsettings-json-from-net-standard-library#comment88136088_50562798) the config classes are supposed to be defined in the target project (in my case the `Model` project) and used in the `OnStartup()` method of the `View` project, so Dependency Injection can be used to pass the config class to the target project, like described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48951371/6919153).

However, for this method to work, I must add a dependency to my `Model` project in my `View` project, so the config class can be accessed there. I believe this would violate the MVVM pattern - at least how I understand it.

How would you tackle this problem? What are the best practices here? Or am I doing things completely wrong? I am also open for suggestions to use a completely different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a dependency to `Model` project in `View` project, because it also serves as composition root for project (contains `OnStartup()` method). Dependency to `Model` is justified.

You don't break MVVM as long as you don't have code in Views which performs operation directly with Model, skipping View Models. Views can be aware of Models (not vice versa), and it can be handy in some situations (e.g. reference some enum from `Model` project in xaml style trigger via `{x:Static model:MyEnum.MyValue}`)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just pass the IConfiguration instance to the `Model` project and handle things from there so that the Configuration setup code (like `configurationBuilder.Configure<MySettingsClas>()`) is no more in the `View` project but in th `Model` project. That way I don't need to add a dependency from the Model to the View.

My `App` class looks like this now:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>());
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it though.

Comment: This works, although the project split feels a bit odd. If the model project contained data access (e.g. from a database) you would define the connection strings in appsettings and instantiate the context/repository in the startup, so you'd need a reference to that project in the view project anyway (or you could have some module discovery with Autofac, etc.)

Although, I'm not so sure I would be using appsettings to define the invoice numbers to exclude though. The invoices must come from some data source - can the data source not have the exclusions?